# Firewall to allow responses but block new connections

Tags: network, firewalls

I wonder if a firewall can support this case. There are two servers: A and B.

- A can send a request via an open port to B and B must respond to A during this connection.
- B cannot send a request on its own to A.

Comment: You described the most basic function of a stateful firewall. Is there a reason that you think that this cannot be done? What challenge do you see?

Comment: @schroeder I have no experience with firewall, because I thought B cannot send data to A so the first requirement "B must respond to A during this connection" might not work.

Comment: I'm very curious how you ran into this problem. Are you configuring a firewall? Is this a homework question?

Comment: @schroeder no it is not my homework, I was curious about how it can be done with a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is a "[stateful firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall)". All firewalls are now Stateful.

This means that the "session" is tracked, not just the bare traffic. So, you can say in the firewall rules that B can *respond* to connections, but not make *new* connections.

Answer (score 1):

First, most firewalls have an OS based on some kind of linux.  Not all firewalls expose access to iptables so your mileage may vary.

For windows you would have to lookup the windows specific commands because windows doesn't have iptables but its own software.

iptables  uses connection tracking.  When setting up rules you can specify NEW and/or ESTABLISHED as options.

In your case I would just specify the ESTABLISHED keyword and not the NEW keyword.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Depend on your kernel and iptables version you may have to use

```
iptables -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
```

Conntrack supersedes state and that should be the preferred method on the newest version of iptables,nftables,kernel and etc.

It is likely you will have to tweak these rules to fit your specific needs.

Comment: thanks for your information, that is helpful for someone learning iptables